# Указатель должен указывать на [указатели]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Нужно объединить и синонимизировать метки [указатель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c) и [указатели](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8).

Основной, я думаю, следует сделать [указатели].

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-разыменовано].

Comment: @NickVolynkin лучше сделать ответ, чтобы можно его было принять и вопрос не бампался.

Comment: @Nofate ответил.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[статус-разыменовано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be).